# jQuery Mobile DateBox & Knockout.js

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, datebox

Has anyone successfully used [jQuery Mobile DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/) with Knockout.js?

I'm having trouble getting the binding to work when providing a value to display before selecting a date. It remains blank. If I use a standard text input, the binding works fine.

```
<input id="start" type="date" data-bind="value: start" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timeflipbox", "useButton": false, "useFocus": true, "dialogForce" : true, "transition" : "slidedown"}'>

//In the view model:
this.start = ko.observable(startTime);
```

I've tried

```
$('#start').datebox('refresh')
```

but no luck....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom binding for knockout which seems to do the trick:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.jqmDateBox = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        setTimeout(function () { 
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
            $(element).val(valueUnwrapped);
            $(element).data('datebox').options.defaultPickerValue = valueUnwrapped;
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<input id="end" name="end" type="date" data-bind="value: end, jqmDateBox: end" data-role="datebox" />
```

Comment: Nice!  any chance you can throw a link in comments here that would be a starting point for someone who has never heard of knockout.js? (Then I will put both in the official docs of jQM-DateBox)

Comment: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ This is what got me started - great interactive tutorials

Comment: cool cool - I am stuck working on a issue with the serving of DateBox right now, but hope to get into the meat and potatos again shortly.  Thanks!

Comment: While I've got you here - how to I set a particular date format? data-options='{"mode": "flipbox", "dateFormat" : "dd MMM yyyy"}' doesn't seem to work?

Comment: David - that is probably an old format string - take a look here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/api/dateformat.html (fwiw, this only affects the output (into the input element)) - if you are playing with event handlers, "theDate" is always going to be a date object.

Comment: oh, also, if you are using a recent version, 'overrideDateFormat':

Answer (score 0):

The binding offered by David didn't work for me. I'm using the latest unstable version of Datebox.

I've written this binding, which works for me in calbox mode:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['dateboxvalue'] = {
  'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

     ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
       var value = valueAccessor();
       value($(element).datebox('getTheDate'));
  });
},
  'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {

    $(element).datebox();
    $(element).datebox('setTheDate', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));
    $(element).trigger('datebox', {'method':'doset'});
  }
};
```

use like this

```
<label for="mode1">CalBox</label>
<input name="mode1" id="mode1" type="text"
       data-role="datebox"
       data-options='{"mode":"calbox", "useNewStyle":true}'
       data-bind="dateboxvalue: myDate"/>
```